# App not installing on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

I am installing an app on a device; using adhoc distribution my app runs fine on two devices but it does not not run on one other device. I have included all the devices in my distribution certificate but still I am unable to solve this.

Is there any possible error for installation which could be possible?

Comment: What does it says when you try to install? Does it install a black screen appears and then the application goes down?

Comment: it just shows alert Cerenia failed to install in alert view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app probably is including the old mobileprovision file, without the UDID of your new device.

Did you download and install the .mobileprovision file with the new UDID included into Xcode Organizer?

Sometimes I've had to go into the Xcode organizer and delete the old .mobileprovision file before Xcode will correctly include the new one in the build.

Comment: i just need to add the distribution mobile provisioning profile in xocde again and first delete old

Answer (score 0):

As the others here mentioned, sometimes things just work out if you try to do it all over again.

- Re-add the phone to your profile in provisioning portal, download it again.
- Remove the old profile from your computer in Xcode -> Organizer -> Devices -> Library/Provisioning Profiles and then install it again.
- Select the profile again in your target, and clean, and then rebuild/archive again.

BUT also make sure to check that the device you are installing on does not have an older **version of iOS** than what is specified in your app's **deployment target**. This happened to me once and the error message is the same.

Answer (score 0):

A way to check for certain that your device is included in the provisioning file is to open up the .ipa file with a program like 7-zip.

Look for the file called embedded.mobileprovision and extract that somewhere. Open it with a text editor, and amid the garbage you'll find a list of the device UDIDs that are provisioned.